# Transferring Image Between Adapters

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-adapter

I have two different adapters: one for a gridView and one for a listView. In my listView, I have a list of the users installed applications with the application icon at the side. In each listView item, I also have a checkbox. When this checkbox is checked, I want it to take the icon of that specific application and then send it over to the gridView where the icon would appear in the gridView.

The issue is that when I click the checkbox, I get this NPE:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AppInfoAdapter$1.onClick(AppInfoAdapter.java:200)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9308)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage  (Handler.java:92)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-22 15:58:45.782: E/AndroidRuntime(28793):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the section of my onClick method for the checkbox:

```
addCheckbox
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");

                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        final int   DEST_IMAGE_WIDTH = 100;
                        final int DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 100;
                        ApplicationInfo appInfo = mContext.getApplicationInfo();
                        Drawable appIcon = pm.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
                        Bitmap appBmp  = Bitmap.createBitmap(DEST_IMAGE_WIDTH, DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT, Config.ARGB_8888); 

                        // Creates a new canvas based on the image specification
                        // created just above.
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(appBmp);
                        // (optional) Fills the entire canvas
                        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                        // You need to set bounds otherwise a 0,0 sized image would be drawn.
                        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, DEST_IMAGE_WIDTH, DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
                        appIcon.draw(canvas);

                        /// Let's save to a .jpg file ...
                        File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/test2.jpg");
                        FileOutputStream out;
                        try
                        {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            appBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
                            Log.i("AppInfoAdapter", "The icon for use in gridView is saved");
                            out.close();

                            // Load back the image file to confirms it works
                          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( file.getAbsolutePath() );
                          ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView_id);
                          imageView1.setImageBitmap( bitmap );  
                          Log.i("AppInfoAdapter", "The icon image has been set into the gridView");
                        }

                        catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
                        {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e2)
                        {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Un-Checked");
                    }

                }
```

Here is line 200:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView_id);
```

and here is the getView() section of my gridView adapter where I want to put the icon image into a view:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    boolean checked = (mCheckBox==null)?false:(((CheckBox)  mCheckBox).isChecked());
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
        view.setId(R.id.iconImageView_id);
    }
    if(checked == true){
        isSdReadable();
        Log.i("GridViewAdapter", "checkbox is checked");

/*FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = Context.openFileInput("BitmapImage");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Load back the image file to confirm it works
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    } else {
        Log.i("GridView", "Icons not for use/checkbox not checked");
    }

    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}
            });
```

I've tried to assign the new view an ID and then set in the image that way ((NOTE IN MY ONCLICK:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView_id);
```

AND IN MY GRIDVIEW:

```
view.setId(R.id.iconImageView_id);
```

))
but this doesn't work and only gives me an NPE because the view heirachies that the two adapters point to are not the same.

So is there a way that I can make them point to the same view heirachy? (Actually, thinking about it now compared to when I first thought of this...

Can I just use a FileinputStream on my gridView adapter to get the image? If so, please tell me how I could go about this. I've already tried this using things such as OpenfileInput but I haven't been able to get it to work.)

ADDED:

Here is the entire getView() for the listView adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get the selected entry
    final ResolveInfo entry = (ResolveInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);

    // reference to convertView
    View v = convertView;

    // inflate new layout if null
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
        Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "New layout inflated");
    }

    // load controls from layout resources
    ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    TextView tvAppName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvPkgName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);
    final CheckBox addCheckbox = (CheckBox) v
            .findViewById(R.id.addCheckbox);
    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Controls from layout Resources Loaded");

    // set data to display
    ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
    tvAppName.setText(entry.activityInfo.loadLabel(mPackManager));
    tvPkgName.setText(entry.activityInfo.packageName);

    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Data Set To Display");
    addCheckbox
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");

                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        final int   DEST_IMAGE_WIDTH = 100;
                        final int DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 100;
                        ApplicationInfo appInfo = mContext.getApplicationInfo();
                        Drawable appIcon = pm.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
                        Bitmap appBmp  = Bitmap.createBitmap(DEST_IMAGE_WIDTH, DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT, Config.ARGB_8888); 

                        // Creates a new canvas based on the image specification
                        // created just above.
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(appBmp);
                        // (optional) Fills the entire canvas
                        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                        // You need to set bounds otherwise a 0,0 sized image would be drawn.
                        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, DEST_IMAGE_WIDTH, DEST_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
                        appIcon.draw(canvas);

                        /// Let's save to a .jpg file ...
                        File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/test2.jpg");
                        FileOutputStream out;
                        try
                        {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            appBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
                            Log.i("AppInfoAdapter", "The icon for use in gridView is saved");
                            out.close();

                            // Load back the image file to confirms it works
                          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( file.getAbsolutePath() );
                          ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView_id);
                          imageView1.setImageBitmap( bitmap );  
                          Log.i("AppInfoAdapter", "The icon image has been set into the gridView");
                        }

                        catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
                        {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e2)
                        {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Un-Checked");
                    }

                }
            });

    // return view
    return v;
}
```

ADDED:
New NPE:

```
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AppInfoAdapter$1.onClick(AppInfoAdapter.java:201)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9308)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-22 22:56:26.852: E/AndroidRuntime(29276):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ADDED 2:
ids.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item type="id" name="iconImageView_id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: please indicate line 200 of `AppInfoAdapter`

Comment: you set click listener for what? `checkBox` or row?

Comment: I set the listener for `checkbox`, when the row is clicked it does something else

Comment: `v.findViewById` is wrong, you must use `yourView.findViewById()` instead of `checkbox.findViewById()`

Comment: Sorry where are you saying that is?

Comment: `v` is `CheckBox` in `onClick()`, for finding your view (`imageVew`) you need use `convertView` that inflated in `getView`, if you post hole code of `getView` i can help you

Comment: Ok, please check under "ADDED". I posted the whole `getView` there

Answer (score 1):

just change name of `v` on `onClick` method to `v1` or anything else, you have

`View v = convertView;`

and:

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

when you use `v` in onClick method you used local `v` that is `CheckBox` in your code, then you don't have `v.findViewById()` in this case because `v` refer to `CheckBox` so you need change the name of one of them.

**// Update**

you got new NPE, as you get that on Line 201,

```
imageView1.setImageBitmap( bitmap );
```

two possibility exists:

1- bitmap is null

2- imageView1 is null

first check  that `iconImageView_id` is exists on `layout_appinfo`, if exists then check bitmap

**// Update 2**

as i see you try add image from one adapter to another adapter, so you have 2 option.

1 - do this work (getting your bitmap) exactly on Grid Adapter ( i don't know what you want exactly but you must send something to that to get right bitmap)

2- get one list of `Bitmap` on `GridAdapter` and fill your `Grid` with that, and add your `bitmap` in `ListAdapter` to that list and call `gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh `gridAdapter`

seconds solution must be worked for you.

Comment: Ok so I changed the `v` in the onClick method to v1 and then changed the v.findViewById to v1.findViewById and ran it and now I got an NPE on line 201 (the line right below)

Comment: `iconImageView_id` is the id I gave the new view in my gridView adapter here : `view.setId(R.id.iconImageView_id);`...I have an `id values` section that is supposed to apparently connect these? Please check the updated answer

Comment: So from this it's probably the iconImageView_id that is returning null

Comment: is `iconImageView_id` exists on `layout_appinfo.xml`?

Comment: No, iconImageView_id isn't on it

Comment: so you got NPE, you try find `iconImageView_id` on `layout_appinfo`,that cause NPE, what you want exactly? why you want set one image to another layout? why you don't pass that?

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue I keep running into. I'm trying to set the image from another adapter to a different one. That's why I was also wondering if I could just use FileInputStream on my gridView adapter and get the bitmap that is saved in the onClick method that way, but I can't get that to work.

Comment: see My new Edit and do second solution

Comment: Ok, I'm kind of confused. So, the `bitmap` is created in the onClick of my checkbox right? So how can I fill my gridView with that bitmap since it's not a specific image in my resources folder? Also, what do you mean by "get on list of `Bitmap`? Can you explain more on the second solution? Thank you by the way for helping me out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48182/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-user2909006)